# Find the latest version of strings - Python

Tags: python

Trying to find the latest version of a list of strings. For example,

```
"01022021_1"
"01032021_1"
"02032021_1"
"02032021_2"
```

The most recent is going to be the last one, but how can I use regex to take those strings and pick out the latest dated and versioned name?

So these are dates with a version number.

Comment: are they dates?

Comment: Yes, they are dates with the versions

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? If they're all padded to the same length and the years don't change, you can use the inbuilt `max()`: `max(["01022021_1",
"01032021_1",
"02032021_1",
"02032021_2"])` gives `'02032021_2'`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - How would that work if the years change?

Comment: would this simply work if the years change as not_speshal said?

Comment: @Epsi95 That won't work because it will put March 2020 ahead of January 2021.

Comment: @caasswa yes. Barmar gives a more robust solution in their answer

Comment: ya, that is correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `max()` with a key that extracts and reorders the parts of the string so the year is most significant.

```
max(yourList, key = lambda s: (s[4:8], s[:4], int(s[8:])))
#                              YYYY    MMDD   VERSION
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, could you explain this a bit more? not sure i understand the 4:8 4 and 8 part

Comment: That's slice notation, it should be familiar to most Python programmers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: oh wait this is just substringing isn't it

Comment: sorry i'm a bit of a noob with python, i'm a C#/C++ programmer so didn't recognise it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the format of your strings (that is (I think), `DDMMYYYY_v`, where `v` is version), then you could use `max()`, as has been suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a list of strings, and the last element in the list is always the latest, the simplest would be the following:

```py
stringlist = [
    "01022021_1",
    "01032021_1",
    "02032021_1",
    "02032021_2"]

latest = stringlist[-1]
print(latest)

# output:
# 02032021_2
```

List handling is extremely easy in python. Using a negative number means you start counting from the end of the list.

Comment: unfortunately. the string is not ordered by default.

Comment: that doesn't matter though, as the OP states *The most recent is going to be the last one,*

Comment: by recent, he probably means recent by time, not by literal order.

Comment: if that's the case, then the excellent answer from Barmar is the best